# How can I create a subclass that takes in different parameters for the same function name?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, interface, subclass

So I have made this simple interface:

```
package{
    public interface GraphADT{
        function addNode(newNode:Node):Boolean;     
    }
}
```

I have also created a simple class Graph:

```
package{

    public class Graph implements GraphADT{

        protected var nodes:LinkedList;

        public function Graph(){
            nodes = new LinkedList();
        }

        public function addNode (newNode:Node):Boolean{
            return nodes.add(newNode);
        }
}
```

last but not least I have created another simple class AdjacancyListGraph:

```
package{
    public class AdjacancyListGraph extends Graph{

        public function AdjacancyListGraph(){
            super();
        }

        override public function addNode(newNode:AwareNode):Boolean{
            return nodes.add(newNode);
        }
}
```

Having this setup here is giving me errors, namely:

```
1144: Interface method addNode in namespace GraphADT is implemented with an incompatible signature in class AdjacancyListGraph.
```

Upon closer inspection it was apparent that AS3 doesn't like the different parameter types from the different Graph classes `newNode:Node` from Graph , and `newNode:AwareNode` from AdjacancyListGraph

However I don't understand why that would be a problem since `AwareNode` is a subClass of `Node`.

Is there any way I can make my code work, while keeping the integrity of the code?

Comment: You are overriding the addNode function to accept AwareNode which should be OK for extending the class but now the interface(s) need to follow that extension of the base class node also. At least that's how it looks to me. I avoid interfaces like the plague.

Comment: @The_asMan, that makes me sad. Interfaces are great things for decoupling, as long as you understand what it is. Its a *contract* that no matter what else your object does, it does *these* things.

Comment: +1 for getting what interfaces are for, @32bitkid.  The only way to achieve a reusable and maintainable architecture.  And an absolute necessessity for unit testing.

Comment: @weltraumpirat you don't need interfaces to achieve quality re-usability. This is OOP there is always another way to achieve the same. But then again its developers design choice.

Comment: @The_asMan I disagree: If you work with a multi-swf architecture, your post-loaded SWF cannot statically depend upon anything in the pre-loaded SWF, unless you embed either the class or an interface.  Which essentially means that if you use only class hierarchies, all the class hierarchy is compiled into the post-loaded SWF.  Bloats your byte code and makes version control almost impossible.  If you use interfaces, both of these problems disappear.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't have it uses. I am just saying there is a very limited need for it and in most cases your traditional class hierarchy will work just fine.

Comment: @The_asMan There are a bunch of patterns that rely heavily on interfaces, and are almost impossible with traditional class hierarchy. You just probably havent run across them yet, but you will. AS3 doesn't support multiple inheritance, but does support implementing multiple interfaces. The visitor pattern, the observer pattern the proxy pattern all rely on interfaces to decouple your code. Why is `IEventDispatcher` an interface and not a class? Look at the unrelated classes that implement it. Even composition-vs-inheritance OOP is easier to do with interfaces. The *interface itself* has value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple answer**:

If you don't really, really need your 'addNode()' function to accept only an AwareNode, you can just change the parameter type to Node.  Since AwareNode extends Node, you can pass in an AwareNode without problems.  You could check for type correctness within the function body :

```
subclass... {
    override public function addNode (node:Node ) : Boolean {
        if (node is AwareNode) return nodes.add(node);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Longer answer**:

I agree with @32bitkid that your are getting an error, because the parameter type defined for addNode() in your interface differs from the type in your subclass.

However, the main problem at hand is that ActionScript generally does not allow function overloading (having more than one method of the same name, but with different parameters or return values), because each function is treated like a generic class member - the same way a variable is.  You might call a function like this:

```
myClass.addNode (node);
```

but you might also call it like this:

```
myClass["addNode"](node);
```

Each member is stored by name - and you can always use that name to access it.  Unfortunately, this means that you are only allowed to use each function name once within a class, regardless of how many parameters of which type it takes - nothing comes without a price: You gain flexibility in one regard, you lose some comfort in another.

Hence, you are only allowed to override methods with the exact same signature - it's a way to make you stick to what you decided upon when you wrote the base class.  While you could obviously argue that this is a bad idea, and that it makes more sense to use overloading or allow different signatures in subclasses, there are some advantages to the way that AS handles functions, which will eventually help you solve your problem:  You can use a type-checking function, or even pass one on as a parameter!

Consider this:

```
class... {

    protected function check (node:Node) : Boolean {
        return node is Node;
    }    

    public function addNode (node:Node) : Boolean {
        if (check(node)) return nodes.add(node);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this example, you could override check (node:Node):

```
subclass... {
    override protected function check (node:Node) : Boolean {
        return node is AwareNode;
    } 
}
```

and achieve the exact same effect you desired, without breaking the interface contract - except, in your example, the compiler would throw an error if you passed in the wrong type, while in this one, the mistake would only be visible at runtime (a `false` return value).

You can also make this even more dynamic:

```
class... {
    public function addNode (node:Node, check : Function ) : Boolean {
        if (check(node)) return nodes.add(node);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this addNode function accepts a Function as a parameter, and that we call that function instead of a class method:

```
var f:Function = function (node:Node) : Boolean {
    return node is AwareNode;
}

addNode (node, f);
```

This would allow you to become very flexible with your implementation - you can even do plausibility checks in the anonymous function, such as verifying the node's content. And you wouldn't even have to extend your class, unless you were going to add other functionality than just type correctness.

Having an interface will also allow you to create implementations that don't inherit from the original base class - you can write a whole different class hierarchy, it only has to implement the interface, and all your previous code will remain valid.

Comment: It's not.  You treat the function like a variable: If it needs reusing, make it a class member (`private var f:Function`(!)). It will then be GC'ed if set to `null`.  If it doesn't, it will be discarded after use like any other temp variable.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the question is really this: What are you trying to accomplish?

As to why you are getting an error, consider this:

```
public class AnotherNode extends Node { }
```

and then:

```
var alGraph:AdjacancyListGraph = new AdjacancyListGraph();

alGraph.addNode(new AnotherNode());  
// Wont work. AnotherNode isn't compatable with the signature
// for addNode(node:AwareNode)

// but what about the contract? 

var igraphADT:GraphADT = GraphADT(alGraph);
igraphADT.addNode(new AnotherNode()); // WTF?
```

According to the interface this should be fine. But your implemenation says otherwise, your implemenation says that it will only accept a `AwareNode`. There is an obvious mismatch. If you are going to have an interface, a contract that your object should follow, then you might as well follow it. Otherwise, whats the point of the interface in the first place.

I submit that architecture messed up somewhere if you are trying to do this. Even if the language were to support it, I would say that its a "Bad Idea™"

Comment: That's not what I'm doing mind you.

I'm simply trying to ask for an `AwareNode` as opposed to the general `Node` . Which to me should be fine because `AwareNode` would have all the required methods to be used as a Node (from the perspective of the interface). Am I right?

Comment: @vvMINOvv but you could. thats the point. that's why the compiler is complaining. because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that, since `AwareNode` would have all the methods in `Node`, if I were to pass in an `AwareNode` into `Graph` it should have no trouble with it, because all the methods it's "used to" are there. That's my understanding of why interfaces are useful, please correct me if I'm wrong :D

Comment: @vvMINOvv Interfaces define a contract of behavior. Your interface says "Hey, I will add any kind `Node` you want." but your implementation says "Nope, I only accept an `AwareNode`". If you implement an interface, you object should be able to act *exactly* as the interface defines.

Comment: thank's a tonne for putting it in lamens terms :D !!

So I know you can extend an interface, but can you override an interface function?

Comment: Of course you can override a function that is defined in the interface - as long as it sticks to the same signature.

Comment: @vvMINOvv a class can implement more than one interface and interface can only extend other interfaces

Comment: @32bitkid your answer was very helpful in understanding interfaces but I have to choose weltraumpirat's answer because he gave me a solution. I wish I could choose both !! :D .. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way, then suggested above, but less safe:

```
public class Parent {
public function get foo():Function { return this._foo; }
protected var _foo:Function = function(node:Node):void { ... }}

public class Child extends Parent {
public function Child() {
super();
this._foo = function(node:AnotherNode):void { ... }}}
```

Of course _foo needs not be declared in place, the syntax used is for shortness and demonstration purposes only.
You will loose the ability of the compiler to check types, but the runtime type matching will still apply.

Yet another way to go about it - don't declare methods in the classes they specialize on, rather make them static, then you will not inherit them automatically:

```
public class Parent {
public static function foo(parent:Parent, node:Node):Function { ... }}

public class Child extends Parent {
public static function foo(parent:Child, node:Node):Function { ... }}
```

Note that in second case protected fields are accessible inside the static method, so you can achieve certain encapsulation. Besides, if you have a lot of Parent or Child instances, you will save on individual instance memory footprint (as static methods therefore static there exists only one copy of them, but instance methods would be copied for each instance). The disadvantage is that you won't be able to use interfaces (can be actually an improvement... depends on your personal preferences).